# LCP - Largest Contentful Paint

Tags: wordpress, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Get a question regarding LCP. When I run the Google PageSpeed Insights.

One of the improvements Google suggested is **Largest Contentful Paint element**.

and it is showing me the following code as an example:

[image]

Is it complaining about the length of the code? or the structure of the code? I don't understand?

Can anyone give me any feedback on what should I change to improve the LCP?

Thank you in advance,

Steve

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://web.dev/lighthouse-largest-contentful-paint/)?

Comment: Read the document that Hernan linked and then see if there is anything else you need help with (you can edit your question). In summary though it is telling you when the largest item (i.e. the element that takes up the most space on the initial screen) is drawn on the screen. It is an indication of when the site "looks" ready to use. The html it highlighted is the element that caused the Largest Paint on the page.

Comment: Hi Hernán Alarcón, yes I did. But still not 100% sure of what I need to do with it after reading it. Thank you. And thank you to Graham Ritchie too for your reply.

Comment: So did what I write previously make sense? If so let me know what you are still struggling with and I will help. If it doesn't then let me know too and I will try to explain a different way! Once you understand what it is measuring it is easier to explain what to look at to fix it.

Comment: Hi Graham, sorry for the late reply. I understand the part where you said "the largest item" and "the HTML element that caused the largest paint".
The part I am confused about is, it doesn't really give a solution. What I did so far, I cache the site, minify the css and js and Lazy Load the images. Not sure if these are relevant to the issue?
Thank you.